# Solving a symmetric system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A & e \\
  e^T & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  x \\
  y
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  b \\
  1
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

where the matrix $A$ is diagonal and $e$ is the one vector $(1,1, ..., 1)^T$.

is there a formula for the solution of this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
  A & e \\
  e^T & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$$
then:

$$M^{-1} =\begin{pmatrix}
  A^{-1} - A^{-1}e(e^TA^{-1}e)^{-1}e^TA^{-1} & A^{-1}e(e^TA^{-1}e)^{-1} \\
  (e^TA^{-1}e)^{-1}e^TA^{-1} & (e^TA^{-1}e)^{-1}
 \end{pmatrix}$$
That is,
$$
M^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}ee^TA^{-1}}{e^TA^{-1}e}
 & \frac{A^{-1}e}{e^TA^{-1}e} \\
 \frac{e^TA^{-1}}{e^TA^{-1}e} & 
 \frac 1{e^TA^{-1}e}
\end{pmatrix} = \\
\frac 1{e^TA^{-1}e}
\begin{pmatrix}
 (e^TA^{-1}e)A^{-1} - A^{-1}ee^TA^{-1}
 & A^{-1}e \\
 e^TA^{-1} & 
 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Of course, this only works when $A$ is invertible!

Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) for more details.

Comment: A lot of this can be simplified by using the fact that $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Note, this matrix may still be invertible when $A$ has a zero diagonal entry, but the formula no longer applies since $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks a lot for the precious improvements to my answer!